# Is there a way to create a list comprehension from this?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I just learned how to create list comprehensions and I was looking back through my past projects to see where I can create comprehensions. I was successful with several, but then I got to this part of the code and I was wondering if there was any way to create a list comprehension from this:

```
scores = util.Counter()

for l in self.legalLabels:
    scores[l] = self.weights[l] * trainingData[i]
```

Maybe I'm just thinking a bit too hard for this but I was wondering if there was any way to create a comprehension using this?

I was thinking something like:

```
[(scores(l) = self.weights[l] * trainingData[I]) for l in self.legalLabels]
```

but this does not work in terms of attributing each value to scores[l].

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's `util.Counter()`, is it a custom object, a dictionary (like `collections.Counter`), or something else?

Comment: @jpp It's a dictionary similar to collections.Counter

Comment: _It's a dictionary_ So `scores` isn't a list at all.  Making it into one is certainly an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `util.Counter()` is a dictionary like [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you can update it with a dictionary via its `update` method. So you can use:

```
scores = util.Counter()
scores.update({L: self.weights[L] * trainingData[i] for L in self.legalLabels})
```

Then for some label `x`, you can access the result via `scores[x]`.

List comprehension are for lists, dictionary comprehensions for dictionaries. The latter are [mentioned in the  docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I didn't pay attention to `scores = utils.Counter()`, so I provided an answer which is `list` comprehension. See @jpp's answer for correct approach.

Your approach is right, but there is no assignment within comprehension. You must make one outside of it

```
scores = [self.weights[l] * trainingData[I]) for l in self.legalLabels]
```

Comment: Oh okay that makes a lot of sense. How would I be able to attribute each of those to scores[i]? Because I want to do `[self.weights[l] * trainingData[I]) for l in self.legalLabels]` for each value in the scores list...

Comment: Can you provide more detail? I don't really understand your question. You want `scores[l] = self.weights[l] * trainingData[I]`with every `l`, is that right?

Comment: Hey, yes that's correct. Let me know if you need more

Comment: This is exactly what my answer do. But, since I didn't pay attention to your `scores=util.Counter()`, means scores is a dictionary, my answer won't work (it's a `list` comprehension). See @jpp 's answer below